# Graphite - calculate the difference of two series containing multiple values

Tags: graphite

I'm using Graphite and Grafana to graph some metrics. Given the following example, is it possible to output a difference that contains multiple values?

```
service.cluster1.host1.quota
service.cluster1.host1.usage
service.cluster1.host2.quota
service.cluster1.host2.usage
service.cluster1.host3.quota
service.cluster1.host3.usage
```

I'm trying to output separate values (based on last) (i.e. quota - usage) for each host. I can display all the data with two separate series using a wildcard for the 'host#' tag, but I'm not certain how I can output the difference per host. My goal is then to use limit() to only display the top few. I've been looking at functions like groupByNode() and diffSeries() but I haven't found a solution. I'm trying to avoid defining a separate series for each host.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled to the following solution using reduceSeries() and mapSeries() (given the previous example data):

```
limit(sortBy(aliasByTags(reduceSeries(mapSeries(service.cluster1.*.*, 2), 'diffSeries', 3, 'quota', 'usage'), 2), 'last', false), 10)
```